# Save graphical content of java applet to image file doesn't work properly

Tags: java, math, applet

I am trying to automatically save the graphic content of a Java applet to an image file but I have an issue that the file doesn't save properly. My complete Java code is:

```
package nl.mark.SierpinskiCarpet;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SierpinskiCarpet extends Applet {
    private Graphics g = null;
    private int d0 = 729; // 3^6
    private BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    private final GraphicsConfiguration gConfig = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
            .getDefaultConfiguration();

    public void init() {
        g = getGraphics();
        resize(d0, d0);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        drawSierpinskiCarpet(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        storeImage();
    }

    public void storeImage() {
        BufferedImage image = create(d0, d0, true);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        // you can disable this if you don't want smooth graphics
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        drawSierpinskiCarpet(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(
                    "N:\\Tapijt van Sierpiński\\image.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private void drawSierpinskiCarpet(int xOL, int yOL, int breedte, int hoogte) {
        if (breedte > 2 && hoogte > 2) {
            int b = breedte / 3;
            int h = hoogte / 3;
            g.fillRect(xOL + b, yOL + h, b, h);
            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
                if (k != 4) {
                    int i = k / 3;
                    int j = k % 3;
                    drawSierpinskiCarpet(xOL + i * b, yOL + j * h, b, h);
                }
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage create(final int width, final int height,
            final boolean alpha) {
        BufferedImage buffer = gConfig.createCompatibleImage(width, height,
                alpha ? Transparency.TRANSLUCENT : Transparency.OPAQUE);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

The image (Sierpinski Carpet) that is shown in the applet is correct but the file that was created is a blank image only. To draw the pattern, the method drawSierpinskiCarpet() is called and after executing the function, the function storeImage() is called to save the image but results in blank image file in the output directory. Whats going wrong during saving of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **NEVER** call `getGraphics` on a component (and **NEVER** store a `Graphics` object that was given as a parameter to `paint` or so).

(And you should never silently swallow an `IOException`. At least add some `e.printStackTrace()` to know when something goes wrong).

The problem here is that you obtained the `Graphics` object from the image, but the call to `drawSierpinskiCarpet` still used the `Graphics g` that was stored as a field in the class.

In this case, one easy solution is to pass the `Graphics` object as a parameter through the recursive calls:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SierpinskiCarpet extends Applet
{
    private int d0 = 729; // 3^6
    private BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    private final GraphicsConfiguration gConfig = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
        .getDefaultConfiguration();

    public void init()
    {
        resize(d0, d0);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        drawSierpinskiCarpet(g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        storeImage();
    }

    public void storeImage()
    {
        BufferedImage image = create(d0, d0, true);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        drawSierpinskiCarpet(g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        try
        {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(
                "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\sierpinskiImage.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void drawSierpinskiCarpet(Graphics g, int xOL, int yOL,
        int breedte, int hoogte)
    {
        if (breedte > 2 && hoogte > 2)
        {
            int b = breedte / 3;
            int h = hoogte / 3;
            g.fillRect(xOL + b, yOL + h, b, h);
            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
                if (k != 4)
                {
                    int i = k / 3;
                    int j = k % 3;
                    drawSierpinskiCarpet(g, xOL + i * b, yOL + j * h, b, h);
                }
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage create(final int width, final int height,
        final boolean alpha)
    {
        BufferedImage buffer =
            gConfig.createCompatibleImage(width, height, alpha
                ? Transparency.TRANSLUCENT : Transparency.OPAQUE);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```